# Suppressing Duplicates on a Sqlite Database

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

I'm trying to suppress duplicates from a table using this request :

```
DELETE FROM tb_entry t1
WHERE entry_id < ANY (SELECT entry_id
FROM tb_entry t2
WHERE t1.entry_id <> t2.entry_id
AND t1.entry_sdate = t2.entry_sdate
AND t1.entry_edate = t2.entry_edate
AND t1.entry_nid = t2.entry_nid
AND t1.entry_msg_grp = t2.entry_msg_grp)
```

The first error I have is:

```
near "t1": syntax error: DELETE FROM tb_entry t1
```

How should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think SQLite allows aliases in `delete`.  Try:

```
DELETE FROM tb_entry
WHERE entry_id > (SELECT MIN(t2.entry_id)
                  FROM tb_entry t2
                  WHERE tb_entry.entry_sdate = t2.entry_sdate AND
                        tb_entry.entry_edate = t2.entry_edate AND
                        tb_entry.entry_nid = t2.entry_nid AND
                        tb_entry.entry_msg_grp = t2.entry_msg_grp
                );
```

I rewrote the logic to refer to the minimum `id`.  I think this is much easier to follow than `< ANY` where the subquery chooses all other ids.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you want to keep the lowest/greatest id for some reason or you don't care which one stays

my advise would be to rely on `GROUP BY` to select one from each set of duplicates

```
DELETE FROM tb_entry
WHERE entry_id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(entry_id)
    FROM tb_entry
    GROUP BY entry_sdate,entry_edate,entry_nid,entry_msg_grp
)
```

example: https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5a8d7f7a293c19gdjdx5xv7h